# php ssh2 connect to HP switch - failing with "Warning: ssh2_exec() [function.ssh2-exec]: Unable to request command execution on remote host"

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

I've been trying to follow the example code found at:

http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/make_ssh_connections_with_php/

I am able to connect to my switch, and successfully authenticate.  BUt when I try to run a command, it fails with the error message in the title of this post.

```
      if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect")) die("function ssh2_connect doesn't exist");
          // log in at server1.example.com on port 22
         if(!($con = ssh2_connect("10.14.123.12", 22))){
            echo "fail: unable to establish connection\n";
            } else {
                 // try to authenticate with username root, password secretpassword
                 if(!ssh2_auth_password($con, "root", "mypassword")) {
                          echo "fail: unable to authenticate\n";
                  } else {
                      // execute a command
                      if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, "show mac-address" ))) {
                           echo "fail: unable to execute command\n";
                      } else {
                             stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
                             $data = "";
                            while ($buf = fread($stream,4096)) {
                             $data .= $buf;
                      }
                      fclose($stream);
                  }
             }
         }
```

It's dying on the line where I'm trying to execute the show mac-address command. 
I've confirmed that this is the correct syntax for the switch command - tried it manually...and it returns data just fine. 
Any suggestions? 
Thanks.

Comment: when you are doing it manually.  Are you sure it's ssh version 2.0 connection?

Comment: i'm using putty... and in the settings, i can see that it has ssh2 selected.

Comment: Is it echoing "fail: unable to execute command\n" or just failing?

Comment: no, actually, i've added another echo statement in the ELSE part of the authenication line and so it explicitly tells me that the authentication passed.  So it fails on the next line when it tries to do the ssh2_exec